# Magento Option Question

Tags: magento

This seems simple enough in theory but I haven't found anything on it. I need it for a client. Please see this page as an example: http://www.customsportsteamuniforms.com/index.php/test-shirt.html

On that page, you will find the first option that says "What kind of Screen Printing do you want?" If you select 1 color and you also happen to want more than 1 quantity (let's say 5), you will end up with this formula for the product cost:

$5 (cost) x $25 (option) x 5 quantity = total.

I DO NOT want it to do that. The option should be a one time fee in this case. The formula should read:

$5 (cost) x 5 quantity = sub-total + $25 (option) = total

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin that does this:

http://www.absolutepricing.com/

Although, in my opinion, this should have been part of the system to begin with, but that's neither here nor there...

Answer (score 0):

Magento's additional fees are all calculated on a per-product basis. If you want to add a fee to the entire order, you'll need to add some custom code to add this as a sort of handling fee for the order. The semantics for this are up to you (for instance, what about 2 different shirts both with 1-color screen printing options).